# C# Linq to MySQL query with join makes bad SQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I'm using C# to write LINQ in to a MySQL database. I think the SQL generated might be wrong for a simple table join that I'm doing.

My nuget packages are Mysql.Data v6.9.9, Mysql.data.entities v6.8.3, and MySql.data.entity v6.9.9

The LINQ is this:

```
query = from peopleResult in query
    join t in technologyQuery on peopleResult.Company_Id equals t.Company_Id
    select peopleResult;
```

The SQL generated looks like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM `people` AS `Extent1` 
INNER JOIN `technologies` AS `Extent2` ON (`Extent1`.`Company_Id` = `Extent2`.`Company_Id`) OR ((`Extent1`.`Company_Id` IS  NULL) AND (`Extent2`.`Company_Id` IS  NULL))
WHERE ...
```

Is this part of the join right?

```
(`Extent1`.`Company_Id` IS  NULL) AND (`Extent2`.`Company_Id` IS  NULL)
```

The query is incredibly long running when that is included. I pulled that out of the SQL with a regex, and it runs much faster and seems to give the correct results.

Is my LINQ incorrect or missing something? Does the MySQL linq-to-sql likely have a bug?

Thank you for your time thinking about this.

Comment: No that is not correct at all, it means your rows will get joined if both sides are null.

Comment: How are you're entities defined?  Specifically the type of the `Company_Id` columns and any relationship between them.

Comment: I'm using database-first entity framework. The Company_Id is a FK in to a companies table for both the people and technologies table. Entity Framework wizard made me the C# people and technology classes with an attribute like this:  public Nullable<long> Company_Id { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a MySQL connector bug, but EF feature which tries to emulate the C# equality rules for nullable types.

First, make sure to set [`DbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextConfiguration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics) to `true`, for instance inside your `DbContext` derived class constructor:

```
Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

By idea this should solve the issue. However they implemented it for comparison operators and forgot the joins. So you have to use the alternative join syntax with `where` clause:

```
query = 
    from peopleResult in query
    from t in technologyQuery
    where peopleResult.Company_Id == t.Company_Id
    select peopleResult;
```

which will be translated to the desired SQL `JOIN` without `IS NULL` part.

Comment: @Erik, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't forget to accept answers that work for you .Click the green checkbox outline.